# Is there a way to make a release note in GitHub downlodable in PDF or any other text file?

Tags: pdf, github, txt, release-notes

I am making use of a GitHub Actions using `release-drafter` which automates the whole process of release notes but I need those notes also in PDF and I could not find any information about PDF in the `release-drafter` documentation. I wonder if there is a way I can download those release-notes in a text document like PDF?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The draft release that's being created on GitHub is written in a dialect of Markdown.  While there isn't an automated process to generate PDFs from this, you can use the GitHub REST API to extract the text from the draft release and pipe it through a tool like `pandoc` to make a PDF out of it.

PDFs, however, are not considered text files, since they can contain arbitrary binary bytes.  If you're looking for just a Markdown file, you can just extract it from the REST API as normal.